# Retrieve specific facts from the Ansible Setup module using JQ

Tags: installation, ansible, jq

I'm trying to pull out data from the setup module in Ansible. I can do most of what I need to but I'm stuck on something that is probably quite simple.

I'm trying to generate a list of hosts including disks + sizes and partitions + sizes AND mount points.

I can get the first two quite easily like this (this should work on any server running on localhost) - I need the sed to format the json correctly:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup | sed '1 s/^.*$/{/' | jq '.ansible_facts | {hostname: .ansible_hostname, Disks: .ansible_devices| with_entries(.value |= .size), Partitions: .ansible_devices[].partitions | with_entries(.value |= .size) }'

{
"hostname": "ip-172-31-16-55",
"Disks": {
  "xvda": "10.00 GB"
  },
"Partitions": {
  "xvda1": "1.00 GB",
  "xvda2": "9.00 GB"
  }
}
```

Now if I want to collect mount points I can do it like this:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup | sed '1 s/^.*$/{/' | jq -r '.ansible_facts.ansible_mounts[].mount'
/
/boot
```

But because the mount information is an array (I think?) i need to map it to get it to work? I'd like to get the results in the same list as the one above but when i add it in it works, but it gives me a new list for every mount point instead of just one list!

This is what I get:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup | sed '1 s/^.*$/{/' | jq '.ansible_facts | {hostname: .ansible_hostname, Disks: .ansible_devices|  with_entries(.value |= .size), Partitions: .ansible_devices[].partitions |  with_entries(.value |= .size), Mounts: .ansible_mounts[].mount }'
{
  "hostname": "ip-172-31-16-55",
  "Disks": {
    "xvda": "10.00 GB"
  },
  "Partitions": {
    "xvda1": "1.00 GB",
    "xvda2": "9.00 GB"
  },
  "Mounts": "/"
}
{
  "hostname": "ip-172-31-16-55",
  "Disks": {
    "xvda": "10.00 GB"
  },
  "Partitions": {
    "xvda1": "1.00 GB",
    "xvda2": "9.00 GB"
  },
  "Mounts": "/boot"
}
```

BUT, this is what I'm trying to get:

```json
{
  "hostname": "ip-172-31-16-55",
  "Disks": {
    "xvda": "10.00 GB"
  },
  "Partitions": {
    "xvda1": "1.00 GB",
    "xvda2": "9.00 GB"
  },
  "Mounts": "/"
  "Mounts": "/boot"
  }
}
```

or even a `,` separated list on one line?

```
  },
  "Mounts": "/", "/boot"
  }
```

I think I can't see the wood for the trees now and a little nudge would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the raw json to your question?

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid json. You cant have 2 `MOunts` keys. An array would be more logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a sample of the relevant JSON, it's a bit difficult to check, but hopefully the following will provide the nudge you're looking for:

```
.ansible_facts
| {hostname: .ansible_hostname,
   Disks: (.ansible_devices | with_entries(.value |= .size)),
   Partitions: ([.ansible_devices[].partitions | with_entries(.value |= .size)]|add),
   Mounts: [.ansible_mounts[].mount]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I was looking for.